# How to enable different theme in WordPress for mobile

Tags: wordpress, mobile, themes, responsive

I want separate theme for my Mobile users of my wordpress website.
Is there any way to achieve this ?
I have searched this terms and there are lots of plugins available but I want to use wordpress core hook and code to switch different theme different laptop and mobile user.

Someone please help me in this regard ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best usage is using media queries for a truly responsive site.

However, you can detect whether the browser is mobile using JavaScript:

```
function isMobile() {
  return /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
}
```

(Source: https://dev.to/timhuang/a-simple-way-to-detect-if-browser-is-on-a-mobile-device-with-javascript-44j3)
(However useragent is potentially unreliable and might show as desktop for iPads.)

You can then hook into the  "switch_theme" function. See:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_theme/

You will likely need this to be in a plugin as in functions.php will be too late.

You can hook into the "switch_theme" function using AJAX, and will have to ensure you use both:
"wp_ajax_" and "wp_ajax_nopriv_" hooks.
Then refresh the page.

This answer for logged-in users might help:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/250575/185854